# How to move contents of a subdirectory in Git to another repository while maintaining each file's history

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I don't think this is a duplicate of the many similar questions that have been asked about this because I am not interested in preserving the history of the subdirectory, just the history of the individual files. I tried the usual:

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter foodir -- --all
```

but I have a dilemma: when I look at the history of the files in the resulting root directory, they only go as far back as when the original subdirectory was created (which I now understand to be expected). What happened was that I had a bunch of files throughout the repo, and i `git mv`ed them into a single, new directory about a week ago. All the individual file histories all the way back to when they were created are there. Now, when I use the subdirectory-filter, the resulting file histories stop when I created the directory. Is there any way to preserve the *entire* history of each file while moving them to another repository?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is no because Git does not track renames. Commands which follow histories of individual files / path prefixes merely use heuristics to detect renames but the repository format itself does not track renames in any way. Since you `git mv`-d your files, your `filter-branch` encantation won't be able to follow their history past the point "foodir" came into existence.

Comment: To make my comment more clear: while `git mv` *looks* like renaming command to a POSIX-aware user, what it does exactly amounts to deleting each file and adding it anew--under a different name.

Comment: Thanks, @kostix, I was worried about that. Luckily all the files have the same prefix so I'm currently trying to use tree-filter and index-filter to delete anything that does not have the prefix. Do you think that might work?

Comment: If they indeed have the same prefix, try `git subtree split` which is tailored for exactly this task!

Comment: Oh, you probably mean the file names have that prefix, not prefix as in "pathname prefix", right? Then `git subtree split ` won't cut it, but tree-filter might.

Comment: Right, yeah the file names are prefixed. Ultimately I was able to somewhat resolve the issue by checking out the commit just before i moved everything, and i used `git subtree split` on each of the individual directories that contained the files, then I replayed later changes manually (PITA) and then merged everything. Ended up keeping 90% of the history which is good enough for our purposes. Thank you for your help!